# Is there an alternative to performing a check constraint with subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, check-constraints

I have two tables

```
Table Room(
  capacity INTEGER,
  roomID varchar(5)
)
```

and

```
Event(
  attendance INTEGER,
  room varchar(5), 
  CHECK(attendance <= (SELECT R.capacity FROM Room R, WHERE R.roomID = room))
)
```

But I guess MySQL doesn't allow for subqueries inside of checks.

Is there an alternative way to perform this check? I only have a passing familiarity with triggers, but it seems like they only allow for explicit actions like insert, delete, etc. I just want to prevent the data from being inserted unless it fits the criteria.

Comment: MySQL parses check clauses but ignores them: **The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.**, source: [CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints.

In some cases, you can use a foreign key constraint instead of a CHECK constraint. For example, let's say you wanted to constrain room.capacity to values between 15 and 100. In other dbms, I'd write a CHECK constraint; for MySQL, I'd use another table and a foreign key constraint.

```
create table capacities (
  capacity integer,
  primary key (capacity)
);

-- Assumes that all the values between 15 and 100
-- are valid capacities. But that's unlikely.
insert into capacities values
(15), (16), (17), (18),
-- . . .
(100);

create table room(
  capacity INTEGER,
  roomID varchar(5),
  primary key (roomID),
  foreign key (capacity) references capacities (capacity)
);
```

In your case, I think you're stuck with writing triggers. First, the table.

```
create table event (
  eventID integer not null,
  attendance integer not null,
  roomID varchar(5) not null,
  primary key (eventID),
  foreign key (roomID) references room (roomID)
);
```

One trigger handles INSERT statements. I didn't look hard; there's probably a better SQLSTATE than '22003'.

```
delimiter $$

create trigger check_capacity_on_insert
before insert on event
for each row begin
if(new.attendance) > (select capacity from room where room.roomid = roomid) then
    signal sqlstate '22003' set message_text = 'Value out of range for room.capacity';
end if; 
end;

$$

delimiter ;
```

And another trigger handles UPDATE statements.

```
delimiter $$

create trigger check_capacity_on_update
before update on event
for each row begin
if(new.attendance) > (select capacity from room where room.roomid = roomid) then
    signal sqlstate '22003' set message_text = 'Value out of range for room.capacity';
end if; 
end;

$$

delimiter ;
```